# Find $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

> $A_t = (\cos t - 2, \cos t + 2) $ for $t \in \mathbb R$. Find $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t$.

Please, help. I have no idea how to correctly solve a task like this, and I can't even find a $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s}$. I understand how to solve much simpler examples, e.g. finding just a $\bigcup$ or $\bigcap$. But what should I do in this case? How to start?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to write down the whole At - $(A_{t0} \cup A_{t1} \cup A_{t2} \cup A_{t3} \cup A_{t4} \cup ...) \cap (A_{t0} \cup A_{t1} \cup A_{t2} \cup A_{t3} \cup A_{t4} \cup ...) .... $ but I don't think that it is a correct way to solve this task. The problem is that I don't know how to use the information that $t \geq s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start out with some examples. Suppose that $s = 0$. Then what is:
$$
\bigcap_{t \geq 0} (\cos t - 2, \cos t + 2)
$$

Well let's think about some examples.

- If $t = 0$, then we have: $(-1, 3)$.
- If $t = \pi/2$, then we have: $(-2, 2)$.
- If $t = \pi$, then we have: $(-3, 1)$.

Draw out these intervals. Where do they all overlap as we keep varying our choice of $t$? It should be easy to see that:

$$
\bigcap_{t \geq 0} (\cos t - 2, \cos t + 2) = (-1, 1)
$$

Now repeat this procedure for a different choice of $s$.

---

EDIT: Here's a full proof.

> **Claim:** $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t = (-1, 1)$

- $\boxed{\subseteq}:$ Choose any $x \in\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t$. Then there is some $s_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{t \geq s_0} A_t$. Now consider $t_{\textsf{even}} = 2|\lceil s_0 \rceil| \pi$ and $t_{\textsf{odd}} = (2|\lceil s_0 \rceil| + 1) \pi$, which are both certainly greater than or equal to $s_0$. Observe that:
  $$
  A_{t_\textsf{even}} = (-1, 3) \\
  A_{t_\textsf{odd}} = (-3, 1)
  $$
  Thus, we conclude that:
  $$
  x \in \bigcap_{t \geq s_0} A_t \subseteq (A_{t_\textsf{even}} \cap A_{t_\textsf{odd}}) = (-1, 3) \cap (-3, 1) = (-1, 1)
  $$
  as desired.
- $\boxed{\supseteq}:$ Choose any $x \in (-1, 1)$. To prove our claim, it is enough to show that $x \in \bigcap_{t \geq 0} A_t$, since this is a subset of $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t$. To this end, choose any $t \geq 0$. We need to show that $x \in A_t$. Indeed, notice that:
  \begin{align*}
  x
  &> -1 &\text{since } x \in (-1, 1) \\
  &= 1 - 2 \\
  &\geq \cos t - 2 &\text{since } \cos t \in [-1, 1] 
  \end{align*}
  Likewise:
  \begin{align*}
  x
  &< 1 &\text{since } x \in (-1, 1) \\
  &= -1 + 2 \\
  &\leq \cos t + 2 &\text{since } \cos t \in [-1, 1] 
  \end{align*}
  Thus, we conclude that $x \in (\cos t - 2, \cos t + 2) = A_t$, as desired.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how exactly $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_{t \geq s} A_t$ is different from $\bigcap_t A_t$ in this example? As you said, I repeated the procedure for different choice of $s$, but as cosinus is a periodic function I still got (-1,1). I thought that I finally understood it, but then I tried to write a formal proof and I got lost again.

Comment: My attempts:
$(\subseteq)$ Suppose $x \in \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_t A_t$. I want to prove, that $x \in (-1, 1)$. I take any $s_0$, $x \in \bigcap_{t \geq s_0}$. I know, that for any $t \geq s_0$, $x \in A_t$. Here I got stuck, so I tried the other way.

Comment: $(\supseteq)$ Suppose $x \in (-1, 1)$. I want to prove, that $x \in \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_t A_t$, so that there exists an $s$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{t \geq s}$. I tried to consider three options you mentioned: $x \in (-1, 3)$,  $x \in (-2, 2)$ ,  $x \in (-3, 1)$, but here I got stuck again. Now it looks like    $x \in \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb R} \bigcap_t A_t$ should be $(-3, 3)$, but it just seems wrong to me.

Comment: @zu_m: I've updated my answer with a full proof.